# Teardown of a int with JUnit 4

Tags: junit, teardown

I was doing several Junit testing on a interface that I implemented.
And in the set-up i declared a :

int counter = 0;

But in the tear down i can't do :
counter = null;

It gives me a message "Type mismatch : cannot convert type from null to int"

How can I tear down my counter variable ?

Comment: A primitive may not be null. Why do you care about resetting the value at the end of the test? It's useless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't tear down primitives, null is a value just for objects.

Change int for Integer or just omit tearing down that reference.